# Tools for seeing how HTML5 web apps will look on devices

Tags: html, web-applications

Are there any tools out there that will allow me to visualize how my web app might look on certain devices? Eg. iPad, Nexus 7, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monaca is a hybrid app development tool which allow you to visualize your app in various smartphones (iPad, iPhone, Nexus 7, Galaxy,... ) on the browser. See the link below:

http://docs.monaca.mobi/en/manual/monaca_ide/interface/#preview-team-panel.

I think you can also develop your app with it. Hope it helps. Cheer.